# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError maven jar

Tags: java, maven

i am new to maven, after running Maven with mvn clean package command.
it compiles the project into an executable jar.

i run the jar in the terminal and got this error:

```
$ java -jar create_pass_criteria-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mprv/automation/core/exceptions/AutomationException
        at Create_pass_criteria.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mprv.automation.core.exceptions.AutomationException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

i have a lot of jars that i use in my code by importing them.
how can i make the jar also include those jars?
is this what this error means?
appreciate any help,
thank you

Comment: It looks like your pom.xml is putting the wrong class in the Manifest - have you verified that `com.mprv.automation.core.exceptions.AutomationException` is in the jar and that the main class is set correctly?

Comment: this is my question, how to set the jar to include ```com.mprv.automation.core.exceptions.AutomationException``` ?
(which is another jar)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

Just add all the required libraries to the classpath when using java -jar target/PriseDeNotes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with the --classpath argument.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).